# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, jdbc

For some reasons the code below does not execute when I try to create a web service to insert id, name and idno into a mysql database. I have added MYSQL JDBC Driver - MYSQL connector library but I get this error "Severe:   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web". 
I have gone through some answers of people but does not seem to get an answer. What could be the cause? Anyone?

```
package com.database.www;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

@WebService(serviceName = "database")
public class database {


    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public void hello(@WebParam() int id, String name, String idno ) {

        try (

                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web", "root", "");
                Statement stm = conn.createStatement();) {



            String insert = "INSERT INTO `web` " + "VALUES ("+id+", '"+name+"','"+idno+"' )";
            int exc = stm.executeUpdate(insert);
            System.out.println("The SQL Command is: " + insert);
            System.out.println("Inserted Successfullly!");
        }
     catch (SQLException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }



    }
}
```

Comment: **How** have you added the mysql connector? And how are you deploying this?

Comment: In the libraries, add library then I picked JDBC Lib on netbeans IDE.

Comment: And how are you deploying it? You should be able to run it in netbeans, but to run it on your server it typically needs to be *installed* on the server.

Comment: What exactly should I install? I am just clicking deploy after clean and build.

Answer (score 0):

I just included `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` and it worked.

```
package com.database.www;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;


@WebService(serviceName = "database")
public class database {


    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public void hello(@WebParam() int id, String name, String idno ) throws ClassNotFoundException {

         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        try (

                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web", "root", "");
                Statement stm = conn.createStatement();) {



            String insert = "INSERT INTO `web` " + "VALUES ("+id+", '"+name+"','"+idno+"' )";
            int exc = stm.executeUpdate(insert);
            System.out.println("The SQL Command is: " + insert);
            System.out.println("Inserted Successfullly!");
        }
     catch (SQLException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }



    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you deploy the driver as part of your web application, instead of having it installed in the application server.

Comment: Note that for modern JDBC driver `Class.forName` should not be necessary.